# Resources to learn how maps are displayed (Under the hood of Leaflet, OpenLayers etc)

Tags: user-interface, leaflet, maps, openlayers

I am interested in learning the foundations of how maps are displayed in GUI, particularly on the web.

Note that I am not talking about the inner workings of GIS, nor which function to call in my javascript to display a Lefalt map. I want to study the underlying principles/concepts/algorithms/architechtures/etc of frameworks such as Leaflet and OpenLayers.

Unfortunately, I found it extremely difficult to find good resources, as when I try to google it I usually end up in an API pages for Leaflet/Openlayers.

Any help will be much appreciated!

Thank you

Comment: Openlayers and Leaflet are open source, so you free to look in the source code on github.

Comment: Generally, when you want to learn general concepts there are a few steps to take before heading to the source code.

E.g, if I wanted to learn how an AVL Trees works, I wouldn't advise anyone to look at the source code, I would direct them to a more high level explanation.

Which is what I asked.

Comment: Ok, then you can learn some webgl and html5 canvas